# Xcode 'Info.plist path not found.'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot compile my project in Xcode, I get the error saying:

[image]
[image]

I'm using CocoaPods and checked if the Info.plist paths in project settings are correct. They are, and the plist files exist in those locations. I have cleaned derived-data and the project but to no avail. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: run pod deintegrate and pod install

Comment: Select that .plist file and in right side in explorer uncheck target membership, And clean project and try again :)

Comment: @Adam try to update your pod using `pod update` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pod deintegrate` and `pod install` worked, can't believe I didn't try that before.

Thank you, [Sachin Vas!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649262/sachin-vas)